# I want to automate the login to a website

Tags: python, browser-automation

I wrote the following code in PyCharm to login to a website automatically:

```
    import requests
    import json

def Login(username, password):
    s = requests.Session()
    payload = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }
    res = s.post('https://domainNamePostUrl', json=payload)
    s.headers.update({'authorization': json.loads(res.content)['token']})
    print(res.content)
    return s


Session = Login('realUserName', 'realPassword')
```

Session = Login('realUserName', 'realPassword') <-- This is line 17

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/venv/bin/python /Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    Session = Login('realUsername', 'realPassword')
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py", line 12, in Login
    s.headers.update({'authorization': json.loads(res.content)['token']})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong and where is the issue coming from?

Comment: `res.content` is not valid JSON. In fact, it appears to be empty.

Comment: Can you mention the website name